# how to specify different imposition schemes per-page

Tags: context

I found this

```
\installpagearrangement 1*4*reversed
   {\dosetuparrangement{2}{2}{4}{3}{3}% X,Y,Total,hcutmarks,vcutmarks
        \pusharrangedpageFOURSINGLESIDEDFOLDEDREVERSED\poparrangedpagesTWO\relax}

\def\pusharrangedpageFOURSINGLESIDEDFOLDEDREVERSED#1%
  {\advancearrangedpageN
   \reportarrangedpage\arrangedpageN
   \ifcase\arrangedpageN
   \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}010\arrangedpageA %  1 rot,hskip,vskip
   \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}111\arrangedpageA %  2
   \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}101\arrangedpageA %  3
   \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}000\arrangedpageA %  4
     \poparrangedpages
   \fi}

\setuppapersize [A10][A8]
\setuparranging [1*4*reversed]
\setuplayout    [margin=0pt, width=fit]

\showframe

\starttext
\dorecurse{4}{\vbox to \textheight{\vfill\midaligned{\tfd ABC}\vfill}\page}
\stoptext
```

imposition scheme in the garden wiki and tried it out. Now i noticed that this sets the imposition scheme for *every* page, but i would like to have a different scheme on the second page (1*4), how do i set that (if this is even possible)?

The result should look like

```
P4 P1
R3 R2

P5 P6
P7 P8
```

where 5-8 should be on the back of 1-4 (double sided), because this gets folded to a flyer.

I'm using ConTeXt LMTX standalone (version 2020.05.09).

Thanks in advacne for any help :)

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on the mailing list https://mailman.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is now part of the [wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Imposition#Custom_imposition_schema). It works by extending the imposition scheme over two physical pages and looks like this:

```
\installpagearrangement 1*4*reversed*1*4
  {\dosetuparrangement{2}{2}{4}{3}{3}% X,Y,Total,hcutmarks,vcutmarks
       \pusharrangedpageFOURSINGLESIDEDFOLDEDREVERSED\poparrangedpagesAB\relax}

\def\pusharrangedpageFOURSINGLESIDEDFOLDEDREVERSED#1%
 {\advancearrangedpageN
  \reportarrangedpage\arrangedpageN
  \ifcase\arrangedpageN
  \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}010\arrangedpageA %  1 rot,hskip,vskip
  \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}111\arrangedpageA %  2
  \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}101\arrangedpageA %  3
  \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}000\arrangedpageA %  4
  \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}000\arrangedpageB %  5
  \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}010\arrangedpageB %  6
  \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}001\arrangedpageB %  7
  \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}011\arrangedpageB %  8
    \poparrangedpages
  \fi}
```

and to quote from the wiki:

```
The \arrangedpageA and \arrangedpageB are box registers that you can use to build up your desired output pages. They actually go up to \arrangedpageH.

Note: if your imposition scheme needs more than eight physical pages see below [Imposition by signatures](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Imposition#Imposition_by_signatures) on how to interface with an external imposer program.
```